# <% %>(without equal) in ruby erb means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i found this "executed with no substitution back into the output" , but maybe my English wasn't too good , i cant really understand what it means. Can anyone help out?

Comment: In the Rails context this sort of thing almost always means 'flow control' -- it's code that doesn't return a value, but rather tells other code whether and when to fire.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<% %>

Will execute Ruby code with no effect on the html page being rendered.  The output will be thrown away.

<%= %>

Will execute Ruby code and insert the output of that code in place of the <%= %>

example...

```
<% puts "almost" %> nothing to see here
```

would render as

```
nothing to see here
```

however

```
<%= puts "almost" %> nothing to see here
```

would render as

```
almost nothing to see here
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you will have to (or you want to) execute some ruby statements but not for output purpose.

like the following:

```
<% if @user.nil? %>
  Hi, welcome!
<% else %>
  Hi, <%= @user.name %>!
<% end %>
```

Of course this is just one use case, but sometimes you do need `<% %>` :D

Answer (score 1):

Code in `<% %>`(without equal) is executed "with no substitution back into the output" means you want to execute code WITHOUT any output, like a loop and the best part is, it can be used with a non ruby code.

```
<% 3.times do %>

<h1>Hello world</h1>

<%end%>

This will give:

<h1>Hello world</h1>  
<h1>Hello world</h1>  
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Comment: ohh , thanks. So with = there must have to be an output!