# link_to not displaying anything rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a hyperlink in the index page but it doesn't show and it doesn't give any errors either.Here is my index.html.erb code.

```
<h1> Listing articles </h1>
<% link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>   <---- Everything works perfectly except this doesnt show anything
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Title</th>
 <th>Textssss</th>
<tr>

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= article.title %> </td> 
     <td><%= article.text %> </td> 
   </tr>
 <% end %>

</table>
```

I have checked my routes and i think they are okay too.

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
    articles      GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
    POST                 /articles(.:format)          articles#create
    new_article  GET      /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
    edit_article GET     /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
    article      GET     /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
      PATCH              /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                 PUT     /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
          DELETE         /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
     root GET            /                            welcome#index
```

i can manually access the article/new from the localhost but i don't think thats the problem.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: add `=` to `link_to`. `<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>` and read about [`ERB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952403/without-equal-in-ruby-erb-means)

Comment: Thanks dude that cleared up alot of things..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax to print anchor tag using rails link_to helper is below. You forgot '=' symbol.

```
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>
```

Ruby code processing within <% %> in ERB template.

```
%  enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %
<% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
<%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
% a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> 
%% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
<%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
```