# Raw Database content showing up in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model-view-controller

You can see [here](https://project-dylanaj5.c9.io/) that it seems like the raw contents of my DB are being printed to the page. I can't see anywhere in my code why there would be the raw output of the db printed to the view. Here is the code for the index view:

```
<div class="main">
    <div="messages">
        <%=@messages.each do |t|%>
        <h2 class="subject"><%=t.subject%></h2>
        <p class="content"><%=t.content%></p>
        <% end %>
        <%=link_to "Create Message", edit_path%>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Create Form/View:

```
<div class="formWrapper">
    <%= form_for @messages do |t|%>
    <div class ="Inputs">
        <%=t.text_field :subject%><br>
        <%=t.text_area :content%>

        <div class="submit">
            <%=t.submit "Submit"%>

        </div>
        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @messages=Message.all
    end
    def new
        @messages=Message.new
    end
    def create
        @messages = Message.new(message_params) 
            if @messages.save 
            redirect_to '/' 
                else 
            render 'new' 
            end
    end
    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:content, :subject)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need the `=` here: `<%=@messages.each do |t|%>`, the equals sign is telling erb to show every message on the view.

`<% %>`

Will execute Ruby code with no effect on the html page being rendered. The output will be thrown away.

`<%= %>`

Will execute Ruby code and insert the output of that code in place of the <%= %>

example...

`<% puts "almost" %> nothing to see here`
would render as

`nothing to see here`

however

`<%= puts "almost" %> nothing to see here`

would render as

`almost nothing to see here`

Look at [<% %>(without equal) in ruby erb means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952403/without-equal-in-ruby-erb-means)

Comment: I edited the answer, with the explanation, if you want to learn more go here: http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/

HAML is another ruby interpreter for html pages, you might want to see it:
http://haml.info/tutorial.html